# take image from UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, xcode6

I have a UITextView containing text only and I want to take a snapshot from it.
I created it programmatically.

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
```

If the  background color of the UITextView is black and the text color is white, I want to parse each pixel to know if I'm on the white or black pixel.

How to do the snapshot to get an image from the UITextView (only if possible) ?

Comment: Please Do some search on How to get screenshot from iOS programatically, Then Limit the area to your TextView Size.

Answer (score 0):

implement this method as UIView category, and you would can draw any UIView as image:

```
- (UIImage*)drawAsImage
{
    // setup context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, 0.0f); // use same scale factor as device
    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // render view
    [self.layer renderInContext:c];

    // get reslting image
    UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method for taking screenshot.

```
 -(UIImage *) screenshot
         {


          CGRect rect;
          rect=yourTextView.Frame;
          UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);

          CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
          [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];

          UIImage *image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
          UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

          return image;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
You can use this method for take the snapshot of the textview.

```
- (UIImage*)screenShotOfView:(UITextView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, YES, 0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    return image;
}
```

And use this code to call the method

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
[self screenShotOfView:textView];
```

Comment: Your answer seems to be what I want to do but is it working even if the UITextView wasn't added to the main view (as subView) ?

Comment: Sure.. You can use the below code to write the image to path. You have to add frame and text before creating the image. Else you will get an empty white image.

NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];