# How can I take a snapshot of a view that is out of the visible bounds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, snapshot

Here's the setup:

1. Main View: (0, 0, 320, 548)
2. Subview 1: (100, 200, 100, 300);
3. Subview 2: (320, 0, 320, 548);

As you can guess the subview 2 is not visible but still inside the main view.

I'm using this code for taking a snapshot:

```
[subview snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:YES];
```

What I'm trying to do is to take a snapshot of the subview 2 (that is out of the visible bounds)
and add it to the subview 1 (that is visible). Imagine it as if the subview 1 is a thumbnail of
the subview 2. Much like when you hover over a window and it shows you a preview.

The problem is that the snapshot view returns black as if the subview 2 was not drawn at all.
Is there a way I can solve this?

The snapshot method has been extensively tested and works fine.

EDIT: Can I force the subview 2 to draw itself?

Comment: take a look at my [answer][1] at this question: 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26970607/3399208

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on the WKWebView, but it works on other views. I need it for a WKWebView.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this – any better?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(yourSubview.frame.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[yourSubview layer] renderInContext: context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```